# Issue with certain mesh vertecies stretching away from bone physics chain

Tags: mesh, rigging, physics, vertices, rigidbody

So i have these two loops that attach to the head of my low poly model

[image: Head at origin point]

but i found out that when I rotated the head certain vertices on the head mesh would stretch away from the bones. I thought that I could just leave it be since it wasn't that noticeable but I later found out that moving the head around from the origin of the "rope" armature  causes the same issue to a more noticeable extent.

[image: the mesh stretching as it moves to the left]

The vertices affected with the problem stretch in the direction of the head being transformed, they act as if they are where they would be if the transformation value was doubled. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the mesh itself at these affected vertices but I am unsure of any way to identify what is wrong with them specifically.

I followed this tutorial for hair physics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02YYfXC7H8U , it's a string of rigid bodies connected by empties.

modifier stack of head mesh:[image: head mesh modifiers]

Comment: Can you add an image of your modifier stack? do you have 2 armature modifiers?

Comment: Yes i do, one for the loops and one for the rest of the armature since i have 2 styles of "hair" on separate layers. 
i'll add the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting some of the deformation applied twice. 
In this case it appears to be a mix between parenting and multiple armatures.

The first thing to do is to check the "Multi Modifier" checkbox on any armature modifiers after the first.

If this doesn't work, you need to use the vertex group field on the armature modifier to make sure each vertex is only influenced by a single armature modifier.

Comment: I did make sure that the vertices of the loop were removed from any vertex group except for loop physics bone groups (And also made sure these loop groups weren't influencing the head).

when i turn on "Multi modifier" on the second armature modifier all the vertices that weren't affected by the issue become affected and the ones that were affected are no longer affected. Strange. 

I'll try using the vertex group field to define the loop vertices and see if that works.

Comment: Its been a while since I set something up like this. You may only need the mask on the second modifier.

Comment: Ok it worked!, though not at first. It did nothing at first but I tried the "Invert Vertex group influence" button next to the textbox and then it worked.

Surprised I couldn't find a similar problem anywhere else, thanks.